# converting nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

We have a table which contains column with datatype `nvarchar(254)`. This column stores date and time in the following format:

```
12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM
```

We need to convert this into `datetime` format so that we can run time dependent queries to extract the required results. This data is not stored in any of the formats mentioned on [CAST and CONVERT documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

I tried with `130` and `131` but no luck.

The format here seems to be `dd-mon-yy hh.mm.ss.mmmmmmm PM`

Does anyone know how should we go about converting this into 'datetime' format?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the long milliseconds after the concert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all it'is a bad idea to store dates as strings. 
[This is a one way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1550) to convert them back to datetime using `STUFF` and `REPLACE` functions.

I assume all your dates are after year 2000.

```
declare @d nvarchar(256) = '12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 
        STUFF(
         REPLACE(REPLACE(
          STUFF(@d, 23, 7, ''), '-',' '),'.',':'), 8,0,'20')  )
```

Comment: @Umarkant if you are satisfied with the answer then you are requested to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @ Anuj Tripathi Done! I missed doing this yesterday, thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to convert your date string into one of those styles supported by SQL Server. In the following example, I target date style 109 (`mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM`):

```
-- character position                0        1         2
--                                   1234567890123456789012345678
DECLARE @DATESTR AS NVARCHAR(254) = '12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 
    SUBSTRING(@DATESTR,  4, 3) + ' ' + -- mon
    SUBSTRING(@DATESTR,  1, 2) + ' ' + -- dd
    SUBSTRING(@DATESTR,  8, 2) + ' ' + -- yy
    SUBSTRING(@DATESTR, 11, 2) + ':' + -- hh
    SUBSTRING(@DATESTR, 14, 2) + ':' + -- mi
    SUBSTRING(@DATESTR, 17, 2) + ':' + -- ss
    SUBSTRING(@DATESTR, 20, 3) +       -- mmm
    RIGHT(@DATESTR, 2)                 -- am/pm
, 109) AS Converted

-- 2015-03-12 16:07:36.000
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you on building ur logic

```
SELECT  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), LEFT('12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM',9), 120) AS DATE) DATE_PART , 
CASE WHEN (RIGHT('12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM', 2)='PM' AND Substring('12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM',  11, 2) <> '12') 
    THEN Cast(Cast(Substring('12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM', 11, 2) AS INT)+12 AS  CHAR(2)) 
 WHEN (RIGHT('12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM', 2)='AM' AND Substring('12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM', 11, 2)='12') 
    THEN '00'
 ELSE Substring('12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM', 11, 2) END + ':' + Substring( '12-MAR-15 04.07.36.000000000 PM',  14, 2) TIME_PART
```